# Can a client Flash (swf file) do the following?

Tags: flash, image-manipulation

I need to make a simple flash program (exported as a swf to be displayed in a webbrowser) that allows a user to *manipulate* an existing image but then SAVE this manipulated image to a webserver.

Can the client side flash program *generate* the new image OR does it need to send back *all the changes* to the web server, which will then generate the new image (based on those changes, via a POST) on the server side?

cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this just fine, Flash has all the bitmap manipulation functions needed for a simple image editing applications. Sending the image back is a matter of a simple post to the server. You might need to compress it first, since sending the raw data will get too big pretty fast.

Comment: Good to hear about the POST - i wanted to do that. So you are saying that i can generate a _new_ bitmap image on the client side and then post this byte[] to the server? As opposed to sending back the changes and having the server generate the new bitmap? any links or examples showing this?

Comment: Here is an article/guide that might help: http://labs.findsubstance.com/2008/04/03/as3-upload-encode-images/

Comment: perfect :) it also highlighted some key ways to do this so when i googled some more, i got more results. perfect :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Look at flash remoting. It's probably easier to just end the entire image back.

I've used http://www.fluorinefx.com/ in the past.

Comment: so are u saying that flash cannot do this? i needs to be done on the server-side?

Comment: Flash is client side technology. If you want to save the image back to the server you are going to have to negotiate with the server somehow. As far as I understand it anyway

Comment: yeah dude. that i know. But that's not the question.  read grapefrukt's reply.